# How can I return user ID with token in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, authorization, token

I generate tokens using default view in Django:

```
url(r'^login/', rest_auth_views.obtain_auth_token),
```

I have a problem because my front-end doesn't know what is the currently logged in user ID.

Should I return it with token or maybe create some another request?

I know that there is a lot of different ways, but I would like to choose the most optimal solution.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could override `rest_framework.authtoken.views.ObtainAuthToken.post` in order to get the result you want.

**myapp/views.py**

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.response import Response


class CustomObtainAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(CustomObtainAuthToken, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        token = Token.objects.get(key=response.data['token'])
        return Response({'token': token.key, 'id': token.user_id})
```

**myapp/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from .views import CustomObtainAuthToken

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^authenticate/', CustomObtainAuthToken.as_view()),
]
```

**Sample results**

```
$ http :8000/authenticate/ username=someuser password=secretpassword
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 22 Mar 2017 18:30:10 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.5.1
Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{
    "id": 16, 
    "token": "82e0bc9980a6b2c9a70969b0f8dc974418dda399"
}
```

The idea here is to override the post method of the ObtainAuthToken view class. Here all I have done is call the parent class to get the token, then look up that token to find the associated user id.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, it helped. This is exactly what I wanted to achieve. I hope that this is consistent solution with the correct habits.

Comment: What should I do if my User table also has a user_type column and I would like to include that in my response? I am currently getting User object first with User.objects.get(id=..) then extracting type information. But it seems like I am running 2 queries to get same user (1 while executing built-in authentication, 1 while getting type). What is the better way of doing this?

Comment: should we add this main views.py file aur in djnago rest view

Answer (score 3):

if you need to get user information on a webpage, you need to pass user information in a response of Login API or other API.

While using Token based authentication, after login, access token and refresh token are generated which are shall be given to client in login API response. This access token shall be passed in header as:

```
Authorization : Bearer <insert token here>
```

You need to put `authentication_classes = [OAuth2Authentication]`
in your view.

This will validate the if user is logged in also you will get to access logged in user's information by `user=request.user`.

Answer (score 3):

I needed more than just user id with the token, so I did code to return the whole user object:

*I use custom user, so if you are using django default user, change model and serializer to default.

```
from users.serializers import CustomUserSerializer
from users.models import CustomUser


class CustomObtainAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(CustomObtainAuthToken, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        token = Token.objects.get(key=response.data['token'])
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=token.user_id)
        return Response({'token': token.key, 'user': CustomUserSerializer(user).data})
```

Thanks to this thread it was easy! Hope my answer will save someones time too. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the good practice will be to return user details in the response of login api.

If your built_in view doesn't return user details you can may be override the post method of `obtain_auth_token`. I once did this for djangorestframework-jwt obtain token method

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        user = serializer.object.get('user') or request.user
        token = serializer.object.get('token')
        response_data = {
            'token': token,
            'user': UserSerializer(user).data
        }
        response = Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        if api_settings.JWT_AUTH_COOKIE:
            expiration = (datetime.utcnow() +
                          api_settings.JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA)
            response.set_cookie(api_settings.JWT_AUTH_COOKIE,
                                response.data['token'],
                                expires=expiration,
                                httponly=True)
        return response

    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

by default `response_data` dict only had `token` details i added user object as well to achieve what you are trying to do.