# Django Rest Framework Serializer - Why isn't my extra field being returned?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, dj-rest-auth

I am trying to return the users id with the token after the user registers but only the token is being returned

I am using dj-rest-auth and [docs](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) say I can serialize extra fields with the RegisterSerializer

My serializer:

```
from dj_rest_auth.registration.serializers import RegisterSerializer


class CustomRegistrationSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_user_id')

    def get_user_id(self, obj):
        o = obj['username']
        user_id = User.objects.get(username=o).id
        print(user_id)
        return Response(user_id)
```

My settings:

```
REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'users.serializers.CustomRegistrationSerializer'
}
```

I am able to print the id in my console, but in the api response it's only returning the token and not the id

Appreciate any help! Don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Also, what is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to return the user id along with the token after i register, but only the token is returned. When i just do user_id i still am able to print the id but it's not getting returned with postman or my frontend

Comment: Found solution with this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44968470/16421620