# Django restful API - get user id with token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How to obtain User ID from Django API having authentication token?
Basically, I want to send authentication token and get back User id.
I have tried this solution: [How can I return user ID with token in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448878/how-can-i-return-user-id-with-token-in-django)
but it is returning token with provided username and password, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 4):

```
#myapp/views.py
class UserIdViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id)

#myapp/urls.py
router.register(r'api/user-id', userviews.UserIdViewSet, base_name="UserId")
```

sort out the problem. Basically created View set and sort this out against current user.

Answer (score 1):

What type of authentication you use ?

If for example, you use TokenAuthentication from rest_framework, you can have a look how this class implements request authentication.

You can find there methods `authenticate` and `authenticate_credentials` and I believe that there - you will find your answer how to get the user.

Comment: I have TokenAuthentication from rest_framework. Will have a look at methods you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

In the perform_create method you can assign the user to your model

```
class EmailViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Email.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmailSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```